# Domain login (windows 7) takes long time on Welcome page

Tags: windows

Log into the domain from Windows 7 is taking quite long time. Is there a way to analyse how long it spends on each stage, e.g. authentication, roaming profile downloading?

I have tried turning on boot log. It does give a long list of processes (binaries) get called, but it does not seem to give intuitive information in this aspect. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Does it log in quickly with no network (using cached credentials)? Duplicate question:http://superuser.com/questions/426029/how-can-i-display-additional-boot-and-shutdown-information-on-the-windows-7-welc

Answer (score 2):

Yes - install and run the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx). It will make it pretty clear.